# I want print the functions one by one in an order like function1 , function2 and function3 so I used call back

Tags: javascript

```js
function display1(res) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('1st message')
    res();
  }, 5000)
}

function display2() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('2nd message')
    res1();
  }, 2000)
}

function display3() {
  console.log('3rd message');
}
display1(display2);
display3();
```

Output :

```
3rd message
1st message
2nd message
```

I am getting this as my output, kindly help me to print 1st message, 2nd message and 3rs message, in this order.

Comment: You're using `res1()` in `display2()`, but it's not defined anywhere, nor is it passed as an argument to use as a callback...

Comment: Well the fact 1 and 2 are asynchronous means not possible unless you rewrite your code. The way it is written it is impossible for 3 to know if 1 and 2 have executed fully.

Comment: Change the timeouts so they're in the order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function display1(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('1st message');
    cb();
  }, 5000);
}

function display2(cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('2nd message');
    cb();
  }, 2000);
}

function display3() {
  console.log('3rd message');
}

display1(display2.bind(null, display3));
```

Will do what you want.

You need to properly take and action the callback in `display2`, and then you also need to use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function, in order to pass the callback (`cb`) as an argument to `display2`, whilst it's already being called as an argument to `display1`.

If you don't use bind, `display1` and `display2` will both execute immediately, which will not give the correct result.

Look in to [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), as that's a much easier way to handle `asynchronous` code.

Answer (score 0):

One easy fix would be:

```
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function display1(res) {
  await timeout(1000);
  console.log("1")
}

async function display2() {
  await timeout(2000);
  console.log("2")
}
function display3() {
  console.log("3")
}


display1().then(() => display2()).then(() => display3());
```

Comment: However async/await is cleaner

Answer (score 0):

use This Way

```js
Promise.resolve('foo')
  .then(function(string) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('strfdfding');
          console.log('first'); 
      }, 2000);
    });
  })
  .then(function(string) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
         resolve('string');
      console.log('second'); 
    }, 1000)
       });
  })
  .then(function(string) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    setTimeout(function() {
         resolve('string');
      console.log('third'); 
    }, 1)
  });
  });
```

[Click here to read more About Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)